# Error when using /var/log

Tags: linux, logs, directory, cat

I have the following in a shell script:

```
cat /var/log
```

And when I run the shell script, in terminal I get:

```
cat: /var/log: Is a directory
```

Answer (score 1):

`/var/log` is a directory and cannot be opened by `cat`.  Perhaps you actually wanted to open one of the files inside `/var/log/`?

Comment: I want to display the log files

Comment: @NataliaElena There are many different log files in the `/var/log` directory. Use `ls /var/log` to see the names of them, and then `cat /var/log/something` to display a particular one (replace `something` with the name of the log file you're interested in).

Comment: @Kusalananda ok, thanks, I'll try this

Comment: @Kusalananda it worked. :)